# Регулярка на выдирание названия директории из пути

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Допустим, есть какой-то путь к файлу.

Мне известно, что начальные несколько уровней могут быть произвольными: их может быть больше или меньше, НО конечные нужные мне N уровней перед файлом не меняются.

Как мне получить регуляркой 1, 2, 3 уровень справа налево от имени файла?

Есть наработки через комбинирование просмотра вперед и назад, но там нужно точно знать кол-во начальных уровней...

Вот у меня такая регулярка:

```
(?<=([/\\].*){9}).*(?=(([/\\].*){2}))
```

Она работает, но нужно задавать окно слева и хочется от этого уйти.

Comment: [`([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(?=(?:[^\/]+)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/f2m9vZ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что правильно понял вопрос, но вроде можно так:

```
([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
```

Всего четыре группы, последняя — имя файла, остальные три — искомые последние уровни

Пример на JavaScript:

```js
const path = '/aaa/bbb/ccc/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt';
const regexp = new RegExp("([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$");
const matches = regexp.exec(path);
const [_, dir1, dir2, dir3, filename] = matches;
console.log(dir1, dir2, dir3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, самое простое, кажется, как-то так:

```
/(.[^\]*){3}$/
```

В зависимости от конкретного диалекта регулярок нужно еще добавить где-нибудь бекслешей.

Вот, например, третья справа группа, перл с юниксовым разделителем в пути:

```
$ echo '123/456/abc/nyan' | perl -nle '/.([^\/]*)(?=(?:.[^\/]*){2}$)/ && print "Four-five-six: $1\n"'
Four-five-six: 456
```

Comment: Почти то, что нужно. Но можно ли получить только конкретный уровень? Сейчас я получаю N уровней.

Comment: Тогда нужен механизм для  lookahead, а в него не каждый regexp engine умеет. Мое, любимое, конечно, вимовское `\ze`: match result в этом месте останавливается, но при этом само сопоставление идет дальше как ни в чем не бывало — если поставить его после первой группы, то в результат только она и попадет.

Comment: Добавил пример на перле для выдирания третьей справа группы.